# Reference List<> object inside static function?

Tags: c#

I need to access my 'files' list from inside the static function. I don't need to modify the contents of the list, I just need to gain access to its contents so I can loop through it in a foreach loop. I'm pretty new to C# but going by knowledge of other languages I assume I need to create an instance of the files list? I Google'd to see how to make an instance of a declared List<> but didn't find anything.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();

private static async Task Search()
{
    string input = "<root>value</root>";
    using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(input), new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
    {

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(file);
            while (await r.ReadAsync())
            {
                switch (r.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        Console.WriteLine(r.LocalName);
                        break;

                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        Console.WriteLine(await r.GetValueAsync());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to use it in static context, `files` has to be static

Comment: Could you please show me this in an answer? Perhaps you could explain why doing that would be better than creating an instance, or is that not necessary here? Thanks :-)

Comment: Please place your code instead of a picture, save effort from those who answer to you

Comment: Can you post code instead of an image?

Comment: Sorry guys, how stupid of me.. doing it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the pattern for a helper method:

```
private static async Task Search(List<string> files){
   //...
}    
//Then just use like this
Search(files);
```

You can also use some extension method for this purpose:

```
public static class StringListExtension {
   public static async Task Search(this List<string> files){
       //...
   }
}
//Then just use like this
files.Search();
```

Comment: Why would this solution be better than simply adding static in front of the files List (as one of the other answers suggests)?

Comment: @JoelKidd I don't say it's better. It's a solution. In many cases you may not want to declare your `List` as static.

Comment: Because, you know, static. The whole setup of the method is weird, why would you have a static method that relies on instance variables? If you want a separate method to operate on one parameter, make it ... a parameter. Then you can even abstract it away into its own class, like `FileSearcher.Search(string[] files)`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ahh well, I didn't know static before I introduced an asynchronous method :P. Thanks though, reading into this more now

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you for the explanation, to `JoelKidd` as I said, it's a common pattern used for helper method (which is static)

Answer (score 1):

In static method you can only use static fields and properties ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

> Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and
>   events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance
>   variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method
>   parameter.

Change files to this:

```
static List<string> files = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

your `List` should be static

```
static List<string> files = ....
```